# C++ Template Specialization and Subclassing

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I was wondering if it is possible to have a template specialization accept a class and its subclasses.  Like so:

```cpp
class A {};

class B : public A {};

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t) {
  printf("T");
}

template <>
void foo(const A& t) {
  printf("A");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  B b;
  foo(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Currently it output 'T' because `b` doesn't have its own template specialization, so it defaults to printing 'T'.  I was wondering if it was possible for `B` to use the template specialization of `A` since `B` is a subclass of `A`.  Or is that just not a thing?

Note: Because of *some* requirement, I can't use copy/move.

Note: I would also prefer if I didn't need to change `A` or `B`, but lets see what is possible first.

Comment: `foo(static_cast<A const &>(b));`? Or simply `foo<A>(b)`?

Comment: Second function does not need to be a function template. Please consider my answer.

Comment: @Jackblue I wrote an answer. If it solved the problem please consider voting/accepting it! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

The probelm is, the primary template is an exact match when `T` being deduced as `B`; it's a better match than the specialization.

You can use template overloading instead; with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T>> foo(const T& t) {
  printf("T");
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>> foo(const T& t) {
  printf("A");
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0MIvvKcIDeCAyHmH)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a cleaner way to do this.  But if you change the actual implementation of foo to a SFINAE [functionoid object](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#functionoids) like std::hash, you can keep your default overload without polluting it with all the potential overload conditions. (Credit [Arthur O'Dwyer's blog](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/04/26/std-hash-should-take-another-template-parameter/)).

```cpp
class A {};

class B : public A {};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct FooImpl {
    static void foo(const T& a) {
        printf("B");
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct FooImpl<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>>> {
static void foo(const T& a) {
    printf("A");
}
};

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t) {
    FooImpl<T>::foo(t);
}
```

Comment: Calling functions is not free of overheads. Please consider my answer which is also similar.

Comment: @AKL Any optimizer will entirely inline all these `foo` functions, making them equivalent to a straight `printf` call.

Comment: @aschepler , you are right in general! But if there is a solution with lower overheads, it is always better to implement that, instead!

Comment: @aschepler , now that I am thinking I am not sure that you are right in general! What if one chooses to turn off optimizations? Shouldn't "Write the program with lowest overheads as much as possible and hope for the best optimization" be the motto?

Comment: @AKL I don't think so. If turning off optimizations makes a program too slow, well, that's not exactly surprising. But even with optimizations, it's not always the case that a faster function is better. True bottlenecks happen in a small fraction of code, so you'll never notice differences from clever tricks in the other 98+%, unless the old code had a very poor choice of algorithm. But when a clever trick makes the source code more difficult to understand/modify, or more prone to bugs, you WILL feel the pain as a developer. As they say, "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: @aschepler I am somewhat aware that some optimizations done by even adept programmers can be detrimental to usability or/and performance of some  programs. But please answer me straight. Do you really think using this answer is better than my answer? Or to rephrase my question, considering the question that was asked by Jack Blue, do you have any slight reason to think, there might be some limited cases if any, where this answer has an advantage compared to my answer?

Comment: @AKL I would prefer your post's first "Solution", for its simplicity / legibility.

Comment: Dear @aschepler thanks a lot and I appreciate it. But I am really curious to know if there is a case in which Daniel's answer is preferable to mine? it is true that I spent a lot of time for editing my answer and no one even voted for it. But my question was not because of ego(at least I am not contentiously aware of it) but more because I wanted to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible and there is no need for
-copy/move,
-change in the classes,
-change in the body of the functions (including but not limited to *calling another class template static function*),
-change in the return type/s of the function/s,
-or even using a  *constant expression as the return type/s* of the function/s!

**Solution**

It is just needed to have the general function as a function template which employes [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) technique in form of default template type/s argument for extra template type parameter/s in order to avoid the special cases and to have the specialization/s
as normal function/s:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T> > >
void foo(const T& t) {
    printf("T");
}
void foo(const A& t) {
    printf("A");
}
```

**Explanation:**

For general cases the default template type argument
`std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T> > >` 
can be deduced from the first template type argument `T`. Because It exists and it is well defined, function template will be called.

When the function is called with an object of a type based on class `A` because `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T> > >` is not defined the default template type argument does not exists hence template type parameter can not be deduced. So compiler would look for another functions with the same name and similar parameter type so the normal function 
`void foo(const A& t) {   printf("A");}`
would be called and there will be no ambiguity.

***Notes on Usage***

For a new specializations simply add one more similar pseudo class to the (one) function template and write a function(non-template) for the  new  specialization.

If the template default type argument looks big and confusing one can simply create a policy template and use that instead. Like:

```
template<typename T, typename P>
using exclude =  std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<P, T> >;
template <typename T, typename = exclude<T,A> >
void foo(const T& t) {
    printf("T");
}
```

Also since before C++17 certain features are not enabled, for lower C++ versions, one can write the template like:

```
template <typename T, typename  = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type>
```

I addition if one chooses to use solution of @songyuanyao which uses a *constant expression as the return type* of the functions, If the return type of the functions is not `void`, for example `return_type`, 
The solution becomes like:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, return_type> foo(const T& t) {
  printf("T");
  return_type return_value;
  return return_value;
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, return_type> foo(const T& t) {
  printf("A");
  return_type return_value;
  return return_value;
}
```

***Further Example***

Finally for a better understanding of [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) One can consider a not-generally-correct/not-all-encompassing alternative solution which does not require any library:

```
template<bool>
struct ifnot;
template<>
struct ifnot<false> {
    enum {v};
};
template<typename T, typename P>
struct test {
    static T value_of_T();
    static char check(...);
    static int check(P);
    enum {v = sizeof(check(value_of_T())) - 1};
};

template <typename T, bool = ifnot<test<T, A>::v>::v>
void foo(const T& t) {
    printf("T");
}
void foo(const A& t) {
    printf("A");
}
```

Although this solution also works for this specific example, please note that this solution is not always correct. Because it only tests conversion of T to A (which even in itself is not complete and problematic) not the inheritance. Specially for these kind of functions which are supposed to be called with objects of similar types, there is a great chance that  many of these types would be convertible to each other!

I think the proper way for an inheritance test includes non-mutually conversion tests and determining if none of the types is `void*`. All considered It is much better to use std::is_base_of or std::is_base_of_v. However The `struct ifnot` is OK and one can even exchange `std::enable_if` for it with the proper changes in their usage.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
foo(static_cast<A&>(b));
```