# Inserting line at specific row in a text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert a line at a specific row .

I have created a file with 10 lines and I called the function below like this insertAtLine(3,"somedata"); ,however the console became stuck and nothing and the text "somedata" wasn't saved to the file.

```
void insertAtLine(int lineNumber,string line)
{
    ofstream myfile("C:\\Users\\test\\Music\\myfile.txt");

    int counter=0;
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        string str;
        do{
            getline(cin, str);
            if(counter == lineNumber)
            {
                myfile<<line<< endl;
            }
            counter++;

        }while(str!="");
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cerr<<"Unable to open file";

}
```

Comment: The easiest option I see to do that is reading the whole file as lines and store as a `stf::vector<std::string>`, insert the wanted test line and write the vector back to the file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree but is there not a way which is more memory/process efficient?
@Joel this is not the correct way! ```myfile<<line<< endl;```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik getline is reading from console not the file!

Comment: If you can guys post a method that does the functionality I described I will be really happy !

Comment: @AKL, `std::getline()` reads from file as well, as soon parametriesed correctly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I meant in this case it is reading from the cin.

Comment: My advice is to do what @πάνταῥεῖ said in the first comment. That should be the simplest method. If you don't want the vector use 2 different files. One for reading the second for writing.

Comment: @Joel I wrote an answer. If it solved the problem please consider voting and accepting it [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Also consider voting for my other answers :)

Comment: @AKL *is there not a way which is more memory/process efficient?* Yes, but the gains are typically minimal and the difficulty is a couple orders of magnitude greater.

Comment: @AKL You earn reputation by writing good answers, which explain why things work instead of dumping a bunch of code that the OP will probably not understand. Asking someone to upvote all your answers won't do much, because that's serial voting which isn't allowed.

Comment: @FeiXiang In the beginning, I wanted to be just like that! But after writing comprehensive (and mostly, better) answers for some questions and then not getting any vote or even any comment for them, I am genuinely confused as to what type of answer is a good (accepted) answer here! [1 Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104580/c-template-specialization-and-subclassing/56111242#56111242). Also I really don't understand why they are so hard on beginners or questioners (in general) here. So I made a joke  to cheer him up. I did not really expect him to vote for all my answers!

Comment: @FeiXiang but now that you are at it your self, how about you my friend? Don't you want to read all of my answers and also to vote them all up? :) (I am joking!)

Comment: @AKL You earned 200 reputation in the last week which is actually pretty decent, especially since you started less than a month ago. Good answers don't always get upvoted since it depends on lots of other factors such as the popularity of the question. Keep answering questions and you'll get better at it. About this site being hard on beginners, this is a controversial issue here and there's [tons of discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming).

Comment: @FeiXiang I did not earn that much reputation because I am actually good at answering. I earn that much because I spent a lot of time to answer questions. And thank you very **very** much for the  _tons of discussion on meta_. Now I know where to look for! :)

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested one(and according to some professionals, the best) way is to first read and store all the lines of the file in to memory, and then write them all back one by one, but to put the extra line (in between) when the line counter reached the desired line number!

One possible solution looks like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int insertAtLine(const std::string file_name, const std::string line, std::vector<std::string>::size_type lineNumber){
    //the memory storage medium
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    //Reading the file to the storage
    {
        //opening the file for reading from it
        std::ifstream file(file_name);
        //checking if the file has been opened correctly
        if (not file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "can't open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        //Reading
        for (std::string one_line; std::getline(file, one_line);lines.push_back(one_line));
    }
    //Writing the storage to the file
    {
        //opening the file for writing to it
        std::ofstream file(file_name);
        //checking if the file has been opened correctly
        if (not file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "can't open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        //finding out the number of the lines
        const auto lines_count = lines.size();
        //writing
        for (std::string::size_type lines_counter(0); lines_counter < lines_count;  file << lines[lines_counter++] << std::endl){
            //checking the line number and writing the extra line if it is needed
            if(lines_counter == lineNumber) file << line<< std::endl;
        }
    }
    //returning 0 if there was no error to this stage 
    return 0;
}
```

First when the file was opened as a read-only file a vector of type `std::vector<std::string>` was used to store the lines. Second when the file was opened as a write-only file the same vector was pasted back to the file, except this time at the desired line the extra line was pasted first!

As for:

```
for (std::string one_line; std::getline(file, one_line);lines.push_back(one_line));
```

It is equal to:

```
{
    //creating a temporary string to be filled with a line
    std::string one_line;
    //reading one line from the file and putting it in "one_line"" while file has not been ended.
    while( std::getline(file, one_line) ){
        //putting the temporary read line "one_line" in to the vector
        lines.push_back(one_line);
    }
}
```

As for:

```
for (std::string::size_type lines_counter(0); lines_counter < lines_count;  file << lines[lines_counter++] << std::endl){
            //checking the line number and writing the extra line if it is needed
            if(lines_counter == lineNumber) file << line<< std::endl;
        }
```

It is equal to:

```
{
    //creating a counter for the loop
    std::string::size_type lines_counter = 0;
    //writing a line to the file for the amount of the files original line number.
    while( lines_counter < lines_count ){
        //writing an original line from the vector to the file
        file << lines[lines_counter] << std::endl;
        //incrementing the counter
        ++lines_counter;
        //if the line number is reached writing the extra line to the file
        if(lines_counter == lineNumber){
            file << line<< std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::string file_name;
    std::string line;
    std::string::size_type lineNumber;

    std::cin >> file_name;
    std::cin >> line;
    std::cin >> lineNumber;

    return insertAtLine(file_name, line, lineNumber);
}
```

File was `input.txt`:

```
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Runtime console communication:

```
input.txt
hello
2
```

Then file became:

```
line 0
line 1
hello
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Also note how `return insertAtLine(file_name, line, lineNumber);` was used to report back read/write problems to the user!

Good luck!